# Add remember me option in stripe form

Tags: javascript, angular, stripe-payments

I am creating a project using angular6. In my project i am integrating stripe payment in my website. I want to add default remeber me option provided by stripe.

```
 <div id="card-element" class="field"></div>
```

From this i am getting stripe form..but there is no option for remember me.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

From the Stripe website:

> “Remember Me” allows customers to save their payment information for
>   future use using a mobile verification process. “Remember Me” is
>   currently only available for merchants who collect payments using
>   [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/payments/checkout)

It is a default option, and if you want to disable it, you or the customer must contact Strip Customer Support.